# Windows 10 UWP - how lock interaction during some process such as downloading

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, windows-10-universal

Hello I have simple Windows 10 UWP application with One Drive integration.
When I download or upload database it' taking a while, about 3-4 minutes. I want to lock in this moment interaction with application.

Let's say I have function to upload() which uploading database, which I run by click button. When I click I want to show content dialog or whatever with "Uploading"

What is the best approach to achieve this? I think about tasks, async methods, but  I never use this. Can someone give me a simply solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
HitTestVisible = false;
```

This disables any interactions.